# VS Code Error: Can not add index to parent of type array

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This error happens to me when I try to change any preference or settings!

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103943

Comment: @SamBob Thanks for sharing the issue link but so far I tried to understand how to solve it but I didn't get it as I've already seen this GitHub issue before.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the 'code' folder in AppData directly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, see my answer here: [VS Code: "Can not add index to parent of type array."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790629/vs-code-can-not-add-index-to-parent-of-type-array/74010290#74010290)

#### Restated

I had this issue, and the root cause was a typo in my settings. To fix it, I reset my settings as follows:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd-,</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd> on Windows/Linux
2. Click the "sheet" icon to open the settings.json file:

[image]

3. Delete all contents of the file and save.

After resetting the settings, I was able to change the settings without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get an error similar to this when the value of a property in your visual studio code **settings.json** is an array when its supposed to be an an object.

In your case, I believe the parent most object is wrapped in an array like this:

---

**setting.json**

```json
[
   {
     "launch.":{
        "version": "0",
         // other launch settings
     },
      
     // other settings
   }
]
```

You need to remove the array wrapping your root settings object. It should look like this:

---

**setting.json**

```json
 {
   "launch.":{
      "version": "0",
       // other launch settings
   },

   // other settings
 }
```