# VS Code: "Can not add index to parent of type array."

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, error-handling, autosave

On VS Code getting following *error*:

> Can not add index to parent of type array.

I can't turn on auto-save because of this error, but I'm not sure how to fix it :(

Please! Does anyone know what might be causing this??

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and the root cause was a typo in my settings. To fix it, I reset my settings as follows:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd-,</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd> on Windows/Linux
2. Click the "sheet" icon to open the settings.json file:

[image]

3. Delete all contents of the file and save.

After resetting the settings, I was able to change the settings without any issues.